# Mapbox - Can't move the marker when location is activated

Tags: javascript, mapbox

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'XXXXXXX';
              
                  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                      container: 'map',
                      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9', // stylesheet location
                      center: [ 50.545750,26.050366 ],              // starting position [lng, lat]
                      zoom: 9.5                                     // starting zoom
                  });
                    // TODO: Fix glitch, once location is on the user cannot move the marker
                  
                    // Allow draggable
                    var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
                      draggable: true
                    })

                    // Add geolocate control to the map.
                    map.addControl(
                        new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
                            positionOptions: {
                                enableHighAccuracy: true
                            },
                            trackUserLocation: true
                        })
                    );

                  marker.setLngLat([ 50.545750,26.050366]);
              
                  function onDragEnd() {
                      var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
                      var lng = lngLat.lng;
                      var lat = lngLat.lat;
              
                      document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;
                      document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
                  }
                  
                  marker.on('dragend', onDragEnd);
              
                  marker.addTo(map);
```

Hi,
From the code above, everything works the way it's intended however when I activate geolocation then the user cannot move the cursor.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the z-index for the marker and the geolocation circle wasn't set, so the geolocation kinda overlapped the marker making the user unable to move the marker.

There are a few ways that we can add the z-index to the marker.

**1. Get the marker element and add a custom class name with getElement since it's not possible to add className with the mapboxgl.Marker() option at the moment**

**Your js file**

```
marker.getElement().classList.add("my-marker")
```

**Then in your css**

```
.my-marker {

  z-index: 1; // up to you

}
```

**2. Make a custom marker**

**Your js file**

```
var el = document.createElement("div");

el.className = "my-marker";

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el);

marker.setDraggable(true);
```

**then in your css for example:**

```
.my-marker {
  z-index: 1;

background-image: url("https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Mark.png");

  background-size: cover;

  width: 50px;

  height: 50px;

  border-radius: 50%;

  cursor: pointer;
}
```

hope this could help you!